# Convert XML to X12 and X12 to XML

Tags: xml, edi, x12

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert XML to X12 and X12 to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449312/best-way-to-convert-xml-to-x12-and-x12-to-xml)

I am writing c#.net code for convert XML to X12 (270 - medical eligibility request) and then to convert the X12 response (271 - eligibility response) back to XML.

Any ideas and help will be appreciated