# Tools for converting X12 to XML based on an XSD schema

Tags: xsd, biztalk, edi, x12

I am looking for a tool or software library (preferably .Net) for converting edi documents to xml using an xsd schema, as Biztalk does.

In Biztalk you can define which schema file to use in a pipeline, and the generated xml will be based on and validated with that schema.

There are many libraries out there that do the conversion (as per this question: [Best way to convert XML to X12 and X12 to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449312/best-way-to-convert-xml-to-x12-and-x12-to-xml)), but I can't see any where you can set the schema that the conversion is based on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this forum post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f52bf64c-e42b-412c-9aa4-f05d06081586/using-standard-x12-schemas-vs-biztalk-x12-schemas?forum=azurelogicapps

It looks like in the absence of any standard X12 XML schemas at the time, Microsoft produced there own and used these within Biztalk for XML validation and conversion.

So it looks unlikely that there will be anything outside of Biztalk that will be able to use XSD files to convert X12 to XML.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official EDI pack for BizTalk - it is highly recommended you use that "accelerator" vs growing your own.
 What version are you on?

Should be found somewhere here in BizTalk program files:
\BizTalk Server\MSI\Program Files\XSD_Schema\EDI\MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates.exe

Comment: We are on Biztalk 2010. I can't find that file so it may be to early a version for that tool. We are actually trying to get to a solution that will free us from Biztalk.

Comment: Oh no why?  It's a wonderful tool.  I may have the schema pack...  would that help?